# pandas how use groupby with pseudo columns for combination solution

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have this problem ...
In the data, the id is always associated with a color. As it seems, with the same id, I can have 3 different colors.
In the solution I want to show all possible color combinations and in the last column the number of them

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'color': ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'red','blue','orange'],
        'id': [ 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b','b'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df_1 = df.groupby(['color','id'])['id'].agg('count')
print(df_1)

df_2 = df.groupby(['id','color'])['id'].agg('count')
print(df_2)

solution = {'color': ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'orange','red','red'],
        'color_2': ['orange', 'orange', 'red', 'red','orange','orange'],
        'color_3': ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue','green','blue'],
        'count': [ '1', '1', '1', '1','1','1'],
        }
solution_df = pd.DataFrame(solution)

print(solution_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=df.groupby('id')["color"].apply(lambda x:list(x)).reset_index()
print(df1)
    id  color
0   a   [green, red, orange]
1   b   [red, blue, orange]

from itertools import permutations
df1["color2"]=df1["color"].apply(lambda x:[i for i in permutations(x)])
df1=df1.explode("color2")
df1.drop("color",axis=1,inplace=True)
df1[["col1","col2","col3"]]=df1["color2"].apply(pd.Series)
print(df1)

    id               color2       col1  col2    col3
0   a   (green, red, orange)     green     red  orange
0   a   (green, orange, red)     green  orange  red
0   a   (red, green, orange)       red   green  orange
0   a   (red, orange, green)       red  orange  green
0   a   (orange, green, red)    orange   green  red
0   a   (orange, red, green)    orange     red  green
1   b   (red, blue, orange)        red    blue  orange
1   b   (red, orange, blue)        red  orange  blue
1   b   (blue, red, orange)       blue     red  orange
1   b   (blue, orange, red)       blue  orange  red
1   b   (orange, red, blue)     orange     red  blue
1   b   (orange, blue, red)     orange    blue  red
```

Comment: Is this your expected output ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but 
1)i want the colors in three different columns, 2) (green, red, orange) == (green, orange, red) == (red, green, orange) and i need only one with 3 colors 3) one more column show me the sum from 3 colors combination

Comment: Alright, I have split the colors in separate columns. I trying to understand your 2 and 3 point. You mean color1 color2 color3 and No of combinations?

Comment: please copy above code and see the solution_df...like this i need the answer